# Magento: add product automatically via observer

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to add a product automatically via observer when a given one is added to the cart.
I've searched but can only find

- adding products to the cart automatically via a checkbox and
- adding to cart for all products selected automatically.

Can someone give me an example of say, productID == 123 added manually then productID == 333 is added automatically to cart via observer?

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.xml`

```xml
<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
            <your_module>
                <class>your_module/observer</class>
                <method>cartProductAddAfter</method>
            </your_module>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
</events>
```

Then in your `Observer.php`

```php
public function cartProductAddAfter($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if ($product->getId() == 123) {

        $productIdToAdd = 333;
        $qty = 1;

        $productToAdd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productIdToAdd);

        $this->_addProductToCart($productToAdd, $qty);
    }
}
```